# Blazor Component Communication StateContainer Invoke not working

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an AppState service which has the following:

```
public event Action OnDataChanged;
public MyObject CurrentObject { get; private set; }

public void UpdateMyObject(MyObject obj)
        {
            CurrentObject = obj;
            OnDataChanged?.Invoke();
        }
```

In one component, I call `UpdateMyObject`. The `AppState` service does get hit with the correct data, and `OnDataChanged?.Invoke()` is called.

In another component, which is supposed to be subscribed to `OnDataChanged` to make decisions on the data update, I have the following:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        AppStateService.OnDataChanged+= UpdateData;
    }

 private void UpdateData()
    {
        var data = AppStateService.CurrentObject;
    }
```

I've tried to put breakpoints all over the 'listening' component, but nothing gets hit. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and why isn't `UpdateData` method being called on `OnChanged?.Invoke` from the state service? Suggestions on how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my code that works - I built it in a Blazor Server template solution.  I've made your object a string for simplicity.

```
public class AppState
{
    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public event Action? OnDataChanged;

    // This is more normal for events
    public event EventHandler? DataChanged;

    public string? CurrentObject { get; private set; }

    public void UpdateMyObject(string obj)
    {
        CurrentObject = obj;
        OnDataChanged?.Invoke();
        DataChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Service Registration

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
// Set as a singleton as the name suggests it's application specific and not user specific
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppState>();
```

A component to display the state

```
// AppStateComponent.razor
@inject AppState AppStateService
@implements IDisposable
<h3>AppStateComponent</h3>

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    Service ID: @this.AppStateService.Id.ToString()
</div>

<div>
    Data: @this.data
</div>
@code {

    private string data = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.AppStateService.OnDataChanged += UpdateData;
    }

    private void UpdateData()
    {
        data = this.AppStateService.CurrentObject!;
        this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.AppStateService.OnDataChanged -= UpdateData;
    }
}
```

And a test page

```
@page "/"
@inject AppState AppStateService
<div class="m-2 p-2">
    Service ID: @this.AppStateService.Id.ToString()
</div>

<AppStateComponent />

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=UpdateData>Update</button>
</div>

@code {

    private void UpdateData()
    {
        this.AppStateService.UpdateMyObject($"Updated at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    }
}
```

Comment: `AddSingleton<AppState>();` I think this should be AddScoped, otherwise the AppState's instance is shared by all connections.

Comment: @enet - which is why I added the comment - // Set as a singleton as the name suggests it's application specific and not user specific.  Otherwise as you say make it `Scoped`.  Was waiting on feedback.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis yeah, I get this working too on a new blazor server app, but in the enterprise app I'm working on, the same code doesn't hit a breakpoint on the listening component.

Comment: Then you can't be referencing the same object instance.  Add a `Guid` Id to your State Service and check that the Id is the same as I've shown in the answer.  Also note I added the Dispose in the answer.  Is your State Service a Singleton or Scoped service?